# Azure Service Bus Shared Access Authorization rule keys expiration time

Tags: authorization, azureservicebus

The documentation that I found doesn't mention any expiration time for the Shared Access Authorization rules and it's not present in the API.

Is it correct that Shared Access Authorization rule keys never expire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct that Shared Access Authorization rule keys never expire?

This is correct. Shared Access Authorization rule keys never expire by themselves. You will need to regenerate a new rule key to invalidate the existing rule key.

You can however generate a [`Shared Access Signature Token`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas#generate-a-shared-access-signature-token) and make it expire at pre-determined time.